# mysql query for conditions on related tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database

i have a table 'house' with a house id, a table 'room' with a room id, and a relation table for those two tables

```
HOUSE
-----
1 |   house1
2 |   house2
3 |   house3
4 |   house4
5 |   house5

ROOM
------
1 |   kitchen
2 |   bathroom
3 |   garage

HOUSE_ROOMS
------------
id | house_id | room_id  |  size 
=================================

1 | 1 | 1 | 200
2 | 1 | 2 | 300
3 | 2 | 1 | 400
4 | 2 | 2 | 500
5 | 3 | 1 | 500
6 | 4 | 2 | 600
7 | 5 | 1 | 400
8 | 5 | 5 | 300
```

I'm having trouble writing a query that returns an array of house id's by some combined conditions:

example: get all houses with a kitchen sized between 350 and 450 AND a bathroom sized between 450 and 550
-> result should be an array containing house2

anyone know how i should write this query?

Comment: Why did you implemented many-to-many relation? Can one room belong to many houses? I guess not. Then, your relation should be 1-to-many, and, therefore, only one field `house_id` in table `room` is needed.

Comment: well, this is a simplified version of my database filtering out stuff thats not related to my problem. It still needs a many to many relation for other reasons that are not mentioned in this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your IDs are fixed, the following quick query will work:

```
 SELECT HOUSE_ID
   FROM HOUSE_ROOMS
  WHERE (ROOM_ID=2 AND SIZE>=450 AND SIZE<=550)
     OR (ROOM_ID=1 AND SIZE>=350 AND SIZE<=450)
  GROUP BY HOUSE_ID
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ROOM_ID)>1
```

Comment: This query returns houses containing 2 kitchens with valid conditions and 0 bathrooms, so i think the HAVING COUNT(*)>2 isn't strict enough

Comment: Checked your edit and it worked fine, so +1 for this post! I figured out another way because i'm using an algorithm that adds where-conditions to a query fetching id's from the house table. Adding 'exists(SELECT * FROM house_rooms WHERE ...)' did the trick for me